# Find out octagonal elements

Tags: openstreetmap, geometry

Is there a way to find out all the octagonal shaped elements within a dataset?

I'm trying to query OSM to give me all the octagonal shaped buildings in a certain area.

Answer (score 2):

Update:

Assuming you work on normal polygons in PostGIS:

```
select id from table where st_npoints(the_geom) = 8+1;
```

For Multipolygons:

```
select id
from (
    select id, (st_dump(the_geom)).geom as the_geom
    from table
) a
where st_npoints(the_geom) = 8+1;
```

8+1 because Start and Endpoint are the same.

Thanks @vince for the hint.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. If you have questions, please place them in the comments below the question, as described in the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Your SQL is the ***long*** way around the lake to get the value provided by `ST_NPoints()` (and doesn't assure that the figure is *octagonal*).

Comment: Need Reputation of 50 to comment.

Comment: Thanks! Inspired by you I have build a (very very rough) query using ST_ConvexHull to avoid cocave buildings.

`select id from table where ST_NPoints(ST_ConvexHull(ST_Simplify(the_geom, 1))) = 8+1 and ST_NPoints(ST_Simplify(the_geom, 1)) = 8+1 and ST_NPoints(the_geom) > 4;`

Is rough, but for now it works.